# How to set validity in directive (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to set an input validity inside a directive? 
The input present in the directive's template.

Lets say I have template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.val" ng-change="check()">
```

And my directive is like:

```
.directive('myDir', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'trmplate.html',
        link: function (scope) {

          someObj = {val: '123'};

          scope.check = function () {
            var result = false;
            myInput.$setValidity(result); //this is didn't work, $setValidity not a function
          };

        }
      }
    })
```

I'm cannot wrap it with form, because the idea behind it is to allow user to include this input inside user's form.

Comment: What is `myInput`?

Comment: @dfsq To be honest I just didn't know what object should have `$setValidity` method. Somewhere I've found `ngModel.$setValidity()`, somewhere it was `ctrl.$setValidity()`

Comment: If you will require ngModel and important thing is you should give name to that input element then you can access and set $validity of that element using controller (fourth parameter of link function). or see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156602/angularjs-set-validity-in-directive-link-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to retrieve [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) instance associated with the input. Then you call `$setValidity` on this object specifying validation key (required, minlength, customkey, etc.). It will look like this:

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.val" ng-change="check()">',
    link: function(scope, element) {

      var modelController = element.find('input').controller('ngModel');

      someObj = {
        val: '123'
      };

      scope.check = function() {
        var result = false;
        modelController.$setValidity('myrequired', result);
      };

    }
  }
})
```

The most important part here is how to get NgModelController. Below line of code is taking care of it:

```
var modelController = element.find('input').controller('ngModel');
```

Comment: You can expand the function line's parameters `link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller)` and reference the `controller` directly.

Comment: @Mark and also add `require: 'ngModel'`. But no, this `controller` will not be the same as `modelController` in my code. So, no, you can't do what you suggest in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use elem in order to get the controller, just add it as a param to the link function, and set require to ['ngModel'] in order to get the model ctrl.

```
 require: ['ngModel'],
 link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

      someObj = {val: '123'};

      scope.check = function () {
        var result = false;
        ctrl.$setValidity(result);
      };

    }
```

Comment: First of all, `element.controller()` is not jQuery. But most importanly, your answer will throw something like `TypeError: Cannot read property '$setValidity' of undefined`, because controller available as 4th parameter has nothing to do with ngModelController OP needs to retrieve.

Comment: You're right, it's not jQuery, my bad. And I forgot to say that he'll need to add require: ['ngModel'] in order for the ctrl param to work properly, gonna edit my answer.

Comment: I thought that you forgot to add `require: ['ngModel']` but this is anyway doesn't change the fact that it will still be TypeError. It will only work if there is `ng-model` on the `myDir` directive itself. Again, it's not related to he NgModelController of the `input` inside of template.

Comment: I got it working on this jsFiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/vkjcbfdc/ ) and it's not showing any TypeError. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: It is working in your demo because you put `myDir` directive on the input element. However, `<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.val" ng-change="check()">` is part of myDir template. Then it would not work.

Comment: I see, you're right, I was missing the template inside the same directive part, you could then divide the directive in two, one for rendering the input and another for checking the value (like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dyroggyr ) but that would be less efficient than your answer I think.