# AngularJS - Show Custom Error Message using Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Directive to validate IP:PORT**

```
myApp.directive("validateServerAddress", ['input', function (input) {

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        alert('Tese');
        var parts = input.split(":");
        var ip = parts[0].split(".");
        var port = parts[1];
        return validateNum(port, 1, 65535) &&
            ip.length == 4 &&
            ip.every(function (segment) {
            return validateNum(segment, 0, 255);
        });
        scope.validateNum = function(input, min, max) {
            var num = +input;
            return num >= min && num <= max && input === num.toString();
        }
    };
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        link: linker
    };
}]);
```

**HTML Input**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" validate-serveraddress placeholder="255.255.255.255:5000" name="serveraddress" id="serveraddress" class="color-tooltip form-control" ng-model="serveraddress" required>
</div>
```

Until user types a valid IP:PORT address, I need to show custom error message '*Invalid Server Address*'. The directive works well. Below could be used and custom class can be applied, but I need to show the message just like bootstrap shows for required field.

```
    document.querySelector("input").oninput = function (e) {
        this.className = validateIpAndPort(this.value) ? "" : "invalid";
    }
.invalid {
    color: red;
}
```

How can I show custom validation using *ngMessages* via directive as shown in below image ?

[image]

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721551/how-to-set-validity-in-directive-angularjs

Comment: use ngModel in your directive, then ngModel.$validators

Comment: @FetraR could you elaborate with some code snippet or alteration to above directive ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Here you go https://plnkr.co/edit/KI9jAqPRkLTYm5EvBKza?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick directive to validate ip:port I created for you

```
app.directive("validateAddressPort", function() {
  function validateIpAndPort(input) {
          var parts = input.split(":");
          var ip = parts[0].split(".");
          var port = parts[1];
          return validateNum(port, 1, 65535) &&
              ip.length == 4 &&
              ip.every(function (segment) {
                  return validateNum(segment, 0, 255);
              });
      }

      function validateNum(input, min, max) {
        var num = +input;
        return num >= min && num <= max && input === num.toString();
      }
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$validators.invalidaddressport = function(input) {
                if(!input) {
                    return false;
                }
                return validateIpAndPort(input);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

html:

```
    <form name="myForm">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="serveraddress" validate-address-port placeholder="255.255.255.255:5000" name="serveraddress" id="serveraddress" class="color-tooltip form-control" ng-model="serveraddress" required>
      </div>
    </form>
```

and now, you can use ngMessages like:

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.serveraddress.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    <div ng-message="invalidaddressport">Invalid Address:port</div>
</div>
```

my plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/KI9jAqPRkLTYm5EvBKza?p=preview

Comment: Could you tell me what I missed here - https://plnkr.co/edit/uAcISTnCNcfbrQIIcuqS?p=preview

Comment: 1. add ngMessages modules
2. use loginForm as you mentionned in form name="loginForm"

Comment: Its the same. But the message is not disappearing when I type correct server address
`<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" validate-address-port placeholder="255.255.255.255:5000" name="serveraddress" id="serveraddress" class="color-tooltip form-control" ng-model="serveraddress" required>
      </div>
      <span ng-show="myForm.serveraddress.$dirty" ng-message="invalidserveraddress" class="help-block">Invalid Address:port</span>
    </form>
  </body>`