# Set validity in angularjs 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs, components, angular-components

There are many examples online for link functions in Angularjs `.directives` to manipulate the dom with

```
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope,elem, attr,ctrl){
    ctrl.$setValidity('element-name', false);
// and setting has-error
    elem.parent().hasClass('has-error');
```

How is this kind of work done on Angularjs 1.5 es5 `.component`?

I have seen that you can inject `$element,$attrs` although no examples of anyone using them or how to inject `ngModel` as ctrl to use for setting validity. Am I missing something super simple that everyone just knows how to do this or has no one tried using these in components.

Comment: This StackOverflow post should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721551/how-to-set-validity-in-directive-angularjs

Comment: @Pramod_Para I said not a `.directive` I am trying to accomplish this in a component. Or is this just something that can't be done in a component.

Comment: You mean without using any of the angular components?

Comment: @Pramod_Para `.component` is a specific component like an Angular2 component [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Comment: Yes, you can set validity within angular.component. But there is no support link function in it, which you could use to setup validity. But there is an alternative solution you can come up to set validation, which basically involves embedding your elements in the form tag. You can get this form reference in your controller factory function of the component, and set validity.

Comment: @Pramod_Para how would you set the element to have a class of has-error though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138571/discussion-between-pramod-para-and-mjwrazor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set validity within angular.component. But there is no support for link function in it, which you could use to setup validity. But there is an alternative solution you can come up to set validation, which basically involves embedding your elements in the form tag. You can get this form reference in your controller factory function of the component, and set validity.

Comment: Just in case people want to know how to give the input a error or success outline. it depends on what you are using. I am using bootstrap so I put `ng-class="{ 'has-error':  $ctrl.formName.inputName.$invalid, 'has-success': $ctrl.formName.inputName.$valid}" and have `this.$onInit` fn make changes to the validity of inputs.

Comment: as well the connection in my component to the form items were. `this.formName.inputName.$setValidity('formName,inputName', false)` for invalid.